# Are there two different cut scenes for every operation head you take out?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Caution, might contain spoilers, though I'm at 51% completion.

It would appear that some Operation heads would not say a thing when arrested, while others would sing like birds.

Does it depend the order at which you defeat a certain OP Head ?

Example: If I [take out El Emisario](http://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2017/03/ghost-recon-wildlands-bosses.jpg?itok=rzACm_vs) first he'll not say a thing, but If I take him out last, he'd have talked when interrogated during the cut scene ?

Ah, poorly chosen example, my reasoning for asking the question is:

> While going after El Cerebro, they guy I end but getting tells me that I missed the real El Cerebro. He was the first buchon I got for that Head, while the last buchone I captured for the previous Head was the (real) singer that said "You better get a pen and a whole lot of paper" when prompted to talk. Right at the El Cerebro moment I got the feeling If I went after him last then the guy I caught would have ended up being the real deal leading to the Head above him and not just a dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the same cut scene will occur for everyone no matter what order you take them out in.  For your El Emisario example, my reasoning is because:

> [You find him hanging by a noose.](https://youtu.be/b272-Nazf0g?t=21m35s)

Because some of the buchons are killed in some special way like the above or something else happens to them that is "special," I don't think the game has different cut scenes or speeches for each of these key people.  I haven't found any sources stating otherwise.  The only different "ending" is El Sueno's for taking out the entire cartel organization.

Comment: I've added a quick edit with a better example.

Comment: @ИвоНедев even with that example, I still feel that the cut scenes are always the same.  I remember this part of the game.  The "real deal" guy gets away no matter what.  For what it's worth, [the wiki](http://ghostrecon.wikia.com/wiki/El_Cerebro) mentions this as well for El Cerebro, but doesn't state anything about getting the real guy.